# How do I get the average monthly values for columns when I have daily indexed data?

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this. Observation_date is the index and the two columns are values corresponding to different types of observations.

```
observation_date       0        1
2010-01-01        44.500000          0
2010-01-01        62.500000   1.500000
2010-01-01        41.500000          0
2010-01-01        31.500000          0
2010-01-01        32.000000          0
...          
2014-09-30                0   8.500000
2014-09-30                0   9.000000
2014-09-30         4.00000    6.000000
2014-09-30         7.500000          0
2014-09-30         6.000000          0
```

Basically, if an index is duplicated (corresponding to multiple observations for that day), I want the average of those values for that index for its columns (0, 1) so that I now have one index for each date corresponding to the average of the observations (keeping the types of observations separate) for that date. So I'd want it to look like this now where avg corresponds to whatever those averages are:

```
observation_date   0        1
2010-01-01       <avg>     <avg>
2010-01-02       <avg>     <avg>
....
2014-09-30       <avg>     <avg>
2014-09-30       <avg>     <avg>
```

Next, I want to take those daily averages for a given month (as above) and get the average of those values for the month.

So it should look like this now (2010-01 corresponds to January 2010).

```
observation_date   0        1
2010-01       <avg>     <avg>
2010-02       <avg>     <avg>
....
2014-08       <avg>     <avg>
2014-09       <avg>     <avg>
```

What I've tried to do:

```
df[['column1', 'column2']].mean()
```

I thought that this would collapse the indices into the average of the columns, but it just gave me the average of each column and threw out the indices. Maybe I need to use the groupby function?

For the second part, I've tried doing the following:

```
data_monthly = df[['column1', 'column2']].resample('M', how='mean')
```

But it tells me:

```
No numeric types to aggregate
```

Found my solution be casting to numpy float64s.

Comment: What are the `dtypes` of your data frame? Type `df.dtypes` and post the output please.

Comment: column1    object
column2   object
dtype: object

Comment: If I check the type on an individual element in the columns, then they are <class 'decimal.Decimal'>. Perhaps this is an issue?

Comment: Your columns are either all strings or have strings in them. Try casting them to floats.

Comment: I had been using pd.DataFrame.from_records to read from my data source. I suppose that it isn't taking care of the job. I will see if that works.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_records` has a coerce_floats argument. It defaults to false so try calling the method with it set to true.

Comment: I tried it and I am still getting <class 'decimal.Decimal'>. What is the best way to cast the columns to floats?

Comment: There are a few ways to do it but `df['column'] = df.column.astype(float)` will work.

Comment: Okay was able to do that and everything is working out. Thanks for your help. Now I am working on the second part of the issue, where I group by month (got the first part of my question to work).

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful and I was able to solve my problem.